# Sending HTTP request on Android over non TCP transport

Tags: java, android, http

I need to do HTTP transactions over a transport which is not implemented by java Sockets.
What whould be the best approach to do it?

Comment: `over a transport`. What is a transport?

Comment: It's an api implemented by native code libaray doing some custom crypto. The api has connect,senddata,poll,close recvdata, methods